# How to implement empty datarow check with an existing for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable, datarow

I have a method to check for empty datarows. However, due to values I require to check using a `for-loop` with `row` and `column` values, I have yet to find a way to integrate the following method which checks for empty rows to prevent unnecessary checks.

**Running function**

```
int headerRow = getColumnHeaderRowNumber(dt);

int firstDataRow = headerRow + 1;

for (int dataRow = firstDataRow; dataRow < dt.Rows.Count; dataRow++)
{
    //using known column header and data row value, 
    //loops each column to match a column title, maintaining on current row
}
```

**Check empty datarow**

```
if (!(AreAllColumnsEmpty(row)))
{
    //executes if row is not empty
}

bool AreAllColumnsEmpty(DataRow dr)
{
    if (dr == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var value in dr.ItemArray)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Trim() != null && value.ToString().Trim() != "")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify `AreAllColumnsEmpty` method so it becomes reusable, like this:

```
    static bool AreAllColumnsEmpty(DataRow dr, out Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair)
    {
        // contains non-empty columns name and value
        nameValuePair = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (dr == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            DataColumnCollection columns = dr.Table.Columns;
            int columnIndex = 0;

            foreach (var value in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                string valueToString = value.ToString().Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueToString))
                {
                    nameValuePair.Add(columns[columnIndex].ColumnName, valueToString);
                }
                columnIndex++;
            }

            return nameValuePair.Count == 0;
        }
    }
```

`AreAllColumnsEmpty` method loops through each column (cell, field) of the row. Non-empty columns are stored in `Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair` like name-value pairs. `AreAllColumnsEmpty` method returns `bool` value which indicates if row is empty and it has `Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair` as output parameter.

`AreAllColumnsEmpty` method is static, but it doesn't need to be. `Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair` will be reset every time method `AreAllColumnsEmpty` executes.

Line

```
    if (value.ToString().Trim() != null && value.ToString().Trim() != "")
```

is replaced by

```
    string valueToString = value.ToString().Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueToString))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give the solution a try. May I know why do we return `nameValuePair.Count == 0`?

Comment: Of course. `nameValuePair.Count == 0` indicates that all columns (cells, fields) in given row are empty. Non-empty columns are stored in `Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair`. If comparison `nameValuePair.Count == 0` is true, method `AreAllColumnsEmpty` will return `true`. If comparison `nameValuePair.Count == 0` is false, in other words if `Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePair` contains data, that means there are non-empty columns and method `AreAllColumnsEmpty` will return `false`. It is short for `if (nameValuePair.Count == 0) { return true; } else { return false; }`.